# How to create python executable from a .py file that need to read and write .txt files in a separate folder

Tags: python, directory, pyinstaller

I've created a python gui that can store information about the user writing .txt files in a separate folder named encrypted passwords. So it has lines like

```
file = open(file='encrypted passwords\\first password.txt', mode='w')
file.write('123456')
file.close()
```

and

```
password = open(file=('encrypted passwords\\first password.txt'), mode='r').read()
```

and

```
os.unlink('encrypted passwords\\first password.txt')
```

The python script and the 'encrypted passwords' folder are in the same folder and when I run it get no problems.

But when I have created the .exe file using pyinstaller it did not work because it had no 'encrypted passwords' folder!

If I added manually a 'encrypted passwords' folder it worked but is there a way in order to not manually add the folder?

Comment: Have you tried writing the full path of encrypted passwords?

Comment: Your code assumes the `encrypted passwords` directory is a sub-directory of the current working directory, which apparently isn't always the case. You can either use a full path to it or determine its location relative to the `.py` or `.exe` file that is running. For a `.py` script you can usually use its built-in `__file__` attribute. With a pyinstaller `.exe` you can use `sys._MEIPASS` instead. See the [Rᴜɴ-ᴛɪᴍᴇ Iɴғᴏʀᴍᴀᴛɪᴏɴ](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/runtime-information.html#run-time-information) section of the pyinstaller documentation.

Comment: `os.makedirs('encrypted passwords', exist_ok=True)` but `exist_ok=True` works only with newer Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if folder exists and create it only if it not exists

```
import os

if not os.path.exists('encrypted passwords'):
    os.makedirs('encrypted passwords')
```

In newer Python you can use `exist_ok=True` to skip when folder exists

```
import os

os.makedirs('encrypted passwords', exist_ok=True)
```